# Is there a way to copy only unique rows in an Excel worksheet column to another sheet?

Tags: windows, powershell

I use a CSV file as $AgencyMaster with two columns, AgencyID and AgencyName. I currently manually input these from another file, $Excel_File_Path, but I would like to automatically generate $AgencyMaster if possible.

$Excel_File_Path has three worksheets: Sheet1, Sheet2 and Template. Sheet1 and Sheet2 are full of data, while Template is used as a graphical representation of said data which populates based on the AgencyID. I have a script that opens $Excel_File_Path, inputs AgencyID into a specific cell, saves it, then converts it to a PDF. It does this for each AgencyID in $AgencyMaster, which is currently over 200.

In $Excel_File_Path, columns B and C in Sheet1 and Sheet2 contain all of the AgencyIDs and AgencyNames, but there are a bunch of duplicates. I can't delete any of the rows because while they are duplicates in column B and C, columns D, E, F, etc have different data used in Template. So I need to be able to take each unique AgencyID and AgencyName which may appear in Sheet1 or Sheet2 and export them to a CSV to use as $AgencyMaster.

Example:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvRyn.png)

Column B contains the AgencyID and Column C contains the AgencyName. I'd like to export unique values of each from Sheet1 and Sheet2 to CSV $AgencyMaster
I've found how to export it to a different worksheet within the same workbook, just not a separate workbook alltogether. I'd also like to save it as a .CSV with leading 0's in cell A.

```
# Checking that $AgencyMaster Exists, and importing the data if it does
    If (Test-Path $AgencyMaster) {
        $AgencyData = Import-CSV -Path $AgencyMaster 

        # Taking data from $AgencyMaster and assigning it to each variable
        ForEach ($Agency in $AgencyData) { 

            $AgencyID = $Agency.AgencyID
            $AgencyName = $Agency.AgencyName 


            # Insert agency code into cell D9 on Template worksheet
            $ExcelWS.Cells.Item(9,4) = $AgencyID
            $ExcelWB.Save()

            # Copy-Item Properties
            $Destination_File_Path = "$Xlsx_Destination\$AgencyID - 
$AgencyName - $company $month $year.xlsx"

            $CI_Props = @{

                'Path' = $Excel_File_Path;
                'Destination' = $Destination_File_Path;
                'PassThru' = $true;

            } # Close $CI_Props
            # Copy & Rename file
            Copy-Item @CI_Props

        } # Close ForEach

    } # Close IF
```

Comment: have you considered using Excel's `Remove Duplicates`?

Comment: I can't remove any rows because other columns in these rows contain data that a third worksheet uses for calculations. I'm trying to extract the unique rows in columns B and C for a separate CSV to use as variables in my script.

Comment: copy rows from A to C, copy from B to C.  Remove Duplicates?  hard to know best way to help you without more info. I'd prob make an Excel macro before PowerShell/Excel interop.  good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I'm probably not explaining it well, I was hoping the image would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using either `Sort-Object -Unique` or `Group-Object`.

Comment: This looks promising! I'm having trouble getting the -Unique parameter to work when importing data into an array. I'm using $Agency = Import-Excel <xlsx location>, $Agency[2].AGENT and $Agency[2].AGYNAM to generate the array, but Sort-Object -Unique after each variable doesn't remove duplicates. If I put it at the end it does show only unique entries but puts them all in one column. Any ideas?

Comment: This did the trick: Import-Excel C:\test\agencytest2.xlsx | sort AGENT,AGYNAM -Unique ... Thanks!

Comment: I should also state that my final code is: $Agency = Import-Excel C:\test\agencytest2.xlsx | sort AGENT,AGYNAM -Unique
$Agency2 = Import-Excel C:\test\agentest.xlsx | sort AGENT,AGYNAM -Unique

$Agency3 = $Agency2 + $Agency 
$Agency3 | Export-Excel C:\test\mashup.xlsx

$Agency4 = Import-Excel C:\test\mashup.xlsx | sort AGENT,AGYNAM -Unique
$Agency4 | Export-Excel C:\test\final.xlsx